# Как перевести 64 отдельных бита в одно 64-битное значение?

Tags: python

Есть список с 64 битами, например:

```
bits = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Надо все эти биты перевести в одно 64-битное значение.

Comment: к примеру 8f373714acfcf4d0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
res = hex(int("".join(map(str, bits)), 2))
```

результат:

```
In [53]: res
Out[53]: '0xfecefefefefafc00'
```

Answer (score 2):

Еще один вариант, без преобразований в строку:

```py
res = hex(reduce(lambda a, b: (a << 1) + b, bits))
```

или

```py
res = hex(reduce(lambda a, b: a << 1 | b, bits))
```

или

```py
res = hex(reduce(lambda a, b: a * 2 | b, bits))
```

Результат:

```
0xfecefefefefafc00
```

Answer (score 1):

можно так:

```
sum(el * 2 ** i for i, el in enumerate(bits[::-1]))
```